# SQL Finding similarities

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

"Determine if there are actors with the same first name who appeared in the same movie."

This is my task and I'm supposed to do that with subqueries and I just dont really know what else to do. I tried everything with group by, order by and having count but I just don't get to the point where I get the same first name actors with the same movie.

Maybe someone can help me? I am using Sakila Database

```
    SELECT 
a.first_name
,(a.last_name)
,a.actor_id
, f.title
FROM actor a 

JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
JOIN film f ON f.film_id = fa.film_id

JOIN(SELECT b.first_name, COUNT(*)
     FROM actor B
     GROUP BY b.first_name
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) b 
     ON a.first_name = b.first_name
     
     GROUP BY a.last_name
     HAVING COUNT(f.title) > 1
     
     
     
     ORDER BY a.first_name
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and provide a [mre]

Comment: Can't help feeling you've accepted the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT f.title, f.film_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.actor_id
FROM actor a 
JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
JOIN film f ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
WHERE a.first_name IN (
         SELECT a2.first_name
         FROM actor a2
         JOIN film_actor fa2 ON fa2.actor_id = a2.actor_id
         JOIN film f2 ON f2.film_id = fa2.film_id
         WHERE a2.actor_id <> a.actor_id AND f2.film_id = f.film_id
)
ORDER BY f.title ASC, a.last_name ASC, a.first_name ASC
```

Explaining query step-by-step

**`SELECT`** the needed fields from the joined tables

**`JOIN`** the necessary tables

**`WHERE`** (here is the subquery) `a.first_name` is in the set of:

firstnames of actors, different than the current actor (`a2.actor_id <> a.actor_id`) and the film is the same (`f2.film_id = f.film_id`)

The subquery in `where` is a similar select with joins query as the parent query.

PS:

One can do variations on this basic query template:

1. Eg `film_id` can be given as parameter, so one can find all actors with same name for specific film.
2. Also one can `group` and `count` how many actors appeared in same film wih same name eg by grouping on `film_id` and counting.
3. One can even optimise a bit the query by removing unnecessary joins (eg `film.title` may not be needed at all) and so on..

The advantage of having single results returned (instead of tuples or aggregates) is that number of actors with same name in same film is not fixed and manipulating the results, eg by grouping and counting or getting further info for each actor, is easier.

The price is a slightly more complex and potentialy slower query.

Comment: At first sight, it does look like it works.. 
Could you explain your query? I was really struggling with this exercise because I just started to write SQL

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with joins only:

```
select f.title, a1.first_name, a1.last_name as last_name_1, a2.last_name as last_name_2
from film f
inner join film_actor fa1 on fa1.film_id = f.film_id
inner join film_actor fa2 on fa2.film_id = f.film_id
inner join actor a1 on a1.actor_id = fa.actor_id
inner join actor a2 on a2.actor_id = fa.actor_id
where a1.first_name = a2.first_name and a1.actor_id < a2.actor_id
```

Starting from the `film` table, this follows the relationships to `actor` through `film_actor` twice, and then filters on diffrerent actors that have the same first name.

As a result, you get tuples of actors that have the same last name and played in the same film. The inequality condition ensures that there are no "mirror" records (that is, each tuple appears only once per film).

Comment: nice alternative approach to return tuples instead of single results

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use aggregation:

```
SELECT fa.film_id, a.first_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(a.last_name) as last_names,
       GROUP_CONCAT(a.actor_id) as actor_ids
FROM actor a JOIN
     film_actor fa
     ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
GROUP BY fa.film_id, a.first_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Your question doesn't specify what the result set should look like.  This returns one row per actors with the same first name in a film.  The last names are concatenated into a string as are the actor ids.

Comment: nice, simple and handy